# Error on tensoflow training after upgrading RAM

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning

I've tried training a custom object detector before with a 4gb ram and GTX 1050ti, it runs without any error even though it is extremely slow. Now I've upgraded to 8gb and I am now having this error.

> 2017-12-27 18:21:27.928811: E
>   tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_event.cc:49] Error polling for
>   event status: failed to query event: CUDA_ERROR_ILLEGAL_ADDRESS
>   2017-12-27 18:21:27.928841: F
>   tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_event_mgr.cc:203] Unexpected
>   Event status: 1 Aborted (core dumped)

Rerunning the training script after the first attempt:

> 2017-12-27 18:35:26.519028: E
>   tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:638] failed to
>   record completion event; therefore, failed to create inter-stream
>   dependency 2017-12-27 18:35:26.519053: I
>   tensorflow/stream_executor/stream.cc:4624] stream 0xc757670 did not
>   memcpy device-to-host; source: 0x10208489d00 2017-12-27
>   18:35:26.519064: E tensorflow/stream_executor/stream.cc:306] Error
>   recording event in stream: error recording CUDA event on stream
>   0x1201fa60: CUDA_ERROR_LAUNCH_FAILED; not marking stream as bad, as
>   the Event object may be at fault. Monitor for further errors.
>   2017-12-27 18:35:26.519076: E
>   tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_event.cc:49] Error polling for
>   event status: failed to query event: CUDA_ERROR_LAUNCH_FAILED
>   2017-12-27 18:35:26.519084: F
>   tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_event_mgr.cc:203] Unexpected
>   Event status: 1 Aborted (core dumped)